# React-Native:Module 0 is not a registered callable moudle

Tags: react-native

[Problems with the upgrade from 0.25 to 0.27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3YlF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the react native version of the app and the dev server do not match. here is an issue link issue in the react native project on github that has more detail https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7832